# Prop in Vue component is not reactive

Tags: vue.js, vue-props, vue-reactivity

Either I have a basic misunderstanding of Vue.js or I have found a bug. I am able to reproduce this bug (?) in the minimal example below.

The component `App.vue` has a reactive `message` variable, which is passed down to the child `Child.vue` as a prop. This message can be changed with a button. This works fine. However, when you alert the message in the Child, you will always get the first message - it is not updated at all. It seems that the message is only updated in the markup, not in the JavaScript. I am really confused by this behavior.

### App.vue

```
<script setup>
import { ref, computed } from "vue";
import Child from "./components/Child.vue";

let index = ref(0);
let messages = ["hi", "there", "this", "is", "strange"];

let message = computed(() => messages[index.value]);

function change_message() {
    index.value++;
    if (index.value === messages.length) {
        index.value = 0;
    }
}
</script>

<template>
    <Child :message="message"></Child>
    <div>
        <button @click="change_message">Change message</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

### Child.vue

```
<script setup>
const { message } = defineProps(["message"]);
function alert_message() {
    window.alert(message);
}
</script>

<template>
    <h1>
        {{ message }}
    </h1>
    <button @click="alert_message">Alert message</button>
</template>
```

### Demo

[image: demo of the bug]

There is a workaround: Do not destructure the props in the Child. So write `const props = defineProps(["message"]);` and then use `window.alert(props.message);`. However, in a real-world Vue application, this will result in quite bloated code. I do not want to carry the `props.` around all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you destructure the props, you are loosing reactivity, For your case one way could be use [toRefs](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-utilities.html#torefs):

`Child.vue`

```js
<script setup>
import { toRefs } from "vue";

const props = defineProps(["message"]);
const { message } = toRefs(props);

function alert_message() {
  window.alert(message.value);
}
</script>


<template>
  <h1>
    {{ message }}
  </h1>
  <button @click="alert_message()">Alert message</button>
</template>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-water-jwhw90?file=/src/components/Child.vue

Anyway is an standard to use `props.<your_prop>` when it's required, even for in a real-world Vue apps

Comment: Thank you! This works fine. Now, however, I need to write "value" all the time. Is there really no other way? (I am coming from Svelte where all this business with refs and values is not needed, everything is reactive.)

Answer (score 0):

**You can create a reactive object on the parent side component, like this:**

```
 test: reactive({
       value: 1//initial value
    })
```

Note: Don't forget the import: "import { reactive } from 'vue'" and send the test var to the child component.

**And in child component pick up value.**

```
     var { reativeObject } = defineProps({
            test: Object,
          });
     var propertyRef= toRef(reativeObject.value)  //create a reference to the property of the reativeObject
```

**Finally, you can pay attention to changes in value**

```
watchEffect(() => {
  console.log(propertyRef.value.value)
})
```

I base it on "https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-utilities.html#toref".
I hope this helps you.